# NanoFramework ESP32 High Resolution Timer always throws exception

Tags: c#, esp32, nanoframework

I am trying to utilize the ESP32 High resolution timer in Nanoframework, but it seems the code always throws a nullReference exception when executed.

Here is how I initialize the timer:

[image]

Following are the versions of nuget packages I am using:
[image]

Whenever the code is run, the code throws exception when we subscribe to the TimerExpired event:
[image]

Any help on what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with latest nanoFramework version and can not reproduce the problem.
Please supply complete test program and indicate the type of ESP32 board you are running on.